# Connecting to one-note through one-note API without windows azure account

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, office365

In order to connect to one-note API from a .net application, We need client id and client secret. For office 365 account it requires the user to register in windows azure. Is there a way to get the client id/secret for office 365 account without windows azure account ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it without registering your app in Windows Azure.

You do need to register your app with the Microsoft Account Developer Center https://account.live.com/developers/applications/ and that will give you a client ID and secret you can use in your ASP.net site without using Azure.

[image]

Here is a great tutorial walking you from beginning to end: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/OneNoteDev/Getting-Started-with-the-OneNote-API-ASP-NET-Edition